# Matplotlib pdf saving fails when run from console only

Tags: python, ssh, console, matplotlib

I'm rendering some matplotlib plots to PDF using matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf. It works fine when I run it from my (Linux) computer, but if I ssh in to the computer from an external location and run the code, it fails with the following error message.

```
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 343, in figure
    **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 80, in new_figure_manager
    window = Tk.Tk()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1688, in __init__
    self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
_tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable
```

The line in my code at which it fails is *fig = matplotlib.pyplot.figure(figsize=(11.5,14.8))*.

I assume this is something to do with it trying to find the display on which to render the plots, but my code never actually displays them. It only saves to PDF. Is there any way I can work around this issue to get the code to run properly?

Comment: Try the suggestions from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5503601/python-headless-matplotlib-pyplot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code may not display the plots, but it still uses an interactive backend that needs a display.

You could either `ssh -Y user@host` and obtain an X-connection, or, as per suggestion in the link provided by ngurenyaga, edit your code to use a non-interactive backend:

```
matplotlib.use("Agg")
```