# Python Graphing on linux system without xserver

Tags: python, graph

I am new to python and trying to explore graphs, could you please help me understand if I can plot graphs on the console using matplotlib on a linux system that has no XSERVER running?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `matplotlib` with no X server by [setting the backend](http://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#what-is-a-backend) to `Agg`, `PS`, `PDF` or `SVG`, `Cairo` or `GDK` (depending on what kind of file you wish to create). You can set the backend in [your `matplotlibrc` file](http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html), which, depending on your installation, may be in a directory such as `~/` or `~/.matplotlib` or `~/.config/matplotlib/`.

Alternatively, you can set the backend in the script itself. 
Be sure to set the backend first, before importing other modules such as `pyplot`:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("Agg")
```

See this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5503601/190597) for examples.

Comment: Is there no other way to display directly on the console while running the script than saving to file? I am not sure how can i display this file without graphics support on the box. Thanks

Comment: I don't have much experience with this, but there are console image viewers such
as
[feh](http://ubuntuguide.net/feh-lightweight-command-line-command-console-image-viewer-for-linux)
or [fbi](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/gutsy/man1/fbi.1.html). So you
could save the image to a file using matplotlib, and then use subprocess to call
feh or fbi to display the image. [Pygame](http://pygame.org/wiki/about) can also display to the linux frame buffer.