# Access to my website on Heroku

Tags: matplotlib, heroku, flask

I've deployed a Flask application on Heroku server but it isn't working
I see this in the browser

> Application error An error occurred in the application and your page
>   could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs
>   for details.

What causes this error?

I got the following when I run `heroku logs`
What are these things and how can I fix it?

```
2018-04-25T18:51:16.513351+00:00 app[web.1]:     _backend_mod, new_figure_manager, draw_if_interactive, _show = pylab_setup()
2018-04-25T18:51:16.513353+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-ile "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 4, in <module>
2018-04-25T18:51:16.596215+00:00 app[web.1]:     from . import tkagg  # Paint image to Tk photo blitter extension.
2018-04-25T18:51:16.596217+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/tkagg.py", line 5, in <module>
2018-04-25T18:51:16.596218+00:00 app[web.1]:     from six.moves import tkinter as Tk
2018-04-25T18:51:16.596220+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py", line 92, in __get__
2018-04-25T18:51:16.596222+00:00 app[web.1]:     result = self._resolve()
2018-04-25T18:51:16.596223+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py", line 115, in _resolve
2018-04-25T18:51:16.596225+00:00 app[web.1]:     return _import_module(self.mod)
2018-04-25T18:51:16.596227+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py", line 82, in _import_module
2018-04-25T18:51:16.596229+00:00 app[web.1]:     __import__(name)
2018-04-25T18:51:16.596230+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
2018-04-25T18:51:16.596232+00:00 app[web.1]:     import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
2018-04-25T18:51:16.596720+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-04-25 18:51:16 +0000] [9] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 9)
2018-04-25T18:51:16.596241+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter'
2018-04-25T18:51:16.739539+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-04-25 18:51:16 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2018-04-25T18:51:16.741786+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-04-25 18:51:16 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
2018-04-25T18:51:16.862528+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2018-04-25T18:51:16.850843+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
(venv) MacBook-Pro-alkhas-b-Amjad:flaskhpbio joodi$
```

Does this mean there are things missing?

Comment: Do you have the [Heroku CLI](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli) installed? If so, please run `heroku logs`, then [edit] your question to add the output of that command. (If you don't have the CLI installed your best bet is to install it and then proceed as I suggested above.)

Comment: @Chris I have Heroku CLI, this commend `heroku logs` should I run it in my application app directory? If so, I tried it and I got long list

Comment: A long list is good :-). That gives detail about what's failing. Your application is trying to import Tkinter. That won't work on Heroku. Do you know why it's doing that?

Comment: @Chris What is Tkinter and why it won't work on Heroku? I've created virtual environment in my app and I download several packages, but I didn't use Tkinter

Comment: Tkinter is a Python interface to [Tk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tk_(software)), a graphical toolkit. Tkinter is usually included with Python but it doesn't make much sense on the web. A common use would be to build graphical software to run on the desktop.

Comment: @Chris I'm using matplotlib package my website, is that related? and what i supposed to do with Tkinter to get my app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your traceback shows that your application is trying to import [Tkinter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tkinter):

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter'

It sounds like `matplotlib` is the library that's trying to do the import.

Tkinter isn't available on Heroku. The good news is that `matplotlib` supports [multiple backends](https://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#what-is-a-backend), some of which work on headless servers. Try modifying your code to use a different backend, like `Agg`:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')  # Must be done before importing pyplot
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

> If you use the `use()` function, this must be done before importing `matplotlib.pyplot`. Calling `use()` after `pyplot` has been imported will have no effect. Using `use()` will require changes in your code if users want to use a different backend. Therefore, you should avoid explicitly calling `use()` unless absolutely necessary.

You'll have to commit this change and push it to Heroku.

See also [Python Headless MatplotLib / Pyplot](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5503601/354577)