# blank image is saved after not using imshow using matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, matplotlib, keras

I am implementing GAN (generative adversarial network) in keras from [here](https://github.com/Zackory/Keras-MNIST-GAN/blob/master/mnist_gan.py). In this code after every 20 epoch image is showed and saved. But i donot want to show image and just want to save. so i just commented line number 89 from code, which is following:

`plt.imshow(generatedImages[i], interpolation='nearest', cmap='gray_r')`. but after commenting this line blank images saved, and also blank images poped up. but when i remove comment and run full code, images saved properly. accoeding to me `imshow` is used to used images, it doesn't part in constructing images. why this happens.

Comment: `imshow()` is the command that plots the content of the array to the axes, so without it, no images are drawn. What you want is to turn off matplotlib's "interactive" mode

Comment: thnx @DizietAsahi for reply, may you plz help , how to turn off iteractive mode

Comment: Similar question, and already has an accepted answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15713279/calling-pylab-savefig-without-display-in-ipython

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Headless MatplotLib / Pyplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5503601/python-headless-matplotlib-pyplot)

Comment: plt.close() works for me, and it's better solution, because if off interactive mode then image will not display but in background it will open ( i am not sure).