# Google Colab: ImportError: Cannot load backend 'TkAgg' Which requires the 'tk' interactive framework, as 'headless' is currently running

Tags: python, matplotlib, google-colaboratory, python-3.8

I am unable to change backend of matplotlib to tkEgg in Google Colab. Google Colab runtime throws the following error on changing matplitlib backend:

Error

> ImportError: Cannot load backend 'TkAgg' which requires the 'tk'
> interactive framework, as 'headless' is currently running*

My Code :

```
import matplotlib
import tkinter
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Already Tried

I have already tried solution provided [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55811545/importerror-cannot-load-backend-tkagg-which-requires-the-tk-interactive-fra) but it is not working for me.

Answer (score 1):

I understand, as the error shows, that you are running in a headless environment (i.e. `$DISPLAY` is not set). Is there any particular reason you'd want to use `TkAgg` over `Agg` as your backend?

See a related answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5503601/python-headless-matplotlib-pyplot), and the linked duplicate.