# Matplotlib - plt.figure() takes always around 12 seconds to be executed

Tags: python, matplotlib

I realized that the following line in my python plot script is the main bottleneck in my execution time. I wrote a small bash function that tracks the time of the output of any application and prints out the time-in-between the stdout prints. The plot script I am testing is (*snippet*) the following:

```
#!/bin/python
#
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

print ("Start loading and importing")
import sys
sys.stdout.flush()

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.gridspec import GridSpec

print ("Done")
sys.stdout.flush()

print ("Start building fig and gs")
sys.stdout.flush()

# ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ Basic Layout Definition ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~

#sizeHeight=4600
#aRation=1.6
#myDpi=100
#fig = plt.figure(figsize=(sizeHeight/myDpi, sizeHeight/aRatio/myDpi), dpi=myDpi)

fig = plt.figure()
print ("plt.fig done")
sys.stdout.flush()

gs = GridSpec(3, 2, width_ratios=[3, 1], height_ratios=[1, 1, 1], wspace=0.02, hspace=0.03)
print ("gs done")
sys.stdout.flush()

print ("Done")
sys.stdout.flush()
```

Executing it with my bash script (`ts`) gives me the following:

```
~: ts python plotData.py
[ 00s:509ms] : Start loading and importing
[ 02s:041ms] : Done
[ 00s:006ms] : Start building fig and gs
[ 11s:727ms] : plt.fig done
[ 00s:007ms] : gs done
[ 00s:007ms] : Done
```

To ensure that things were correct, I achieve the same with `time`:

```
~: time python plotData.py
Start loading and importing
Done
Start defining settings
Done
Start building fig and gs
plt.fig done
gs done
Done

real    0m14.630s
user    0m2.463s
sys     0m2.146s
```

First, I was expecting that the resolution and DPI I set takes so much time but what-ever I set for the resolution or DPI (lines which are commented), the time-consumption for the `plt.figure()` command is always around 11 s to 12 s.

Can we somehow optimize that? Unfortunately, on the headless node `gnuplot` is not working and I need to use `python`. Any ideas to increase the performance here?

The rest of the script performes quite fast and all 7 plots are created within a few milliseconds. So I am really worried why `plt.picture()` performes so bad here?

Comment: `plt.figure()` is probably starting a chain of system functions which are out of its control. It needs to know the backend, and its features. Maybe something internally is waiting for a timeout.    You could try matplotlib in "headless mode". Like `import matplotlib as mpl; mpl.use('agg'); import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`.  See also [matplotlib backends](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/figure/backends.html), [headless matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5503601/python-headless-matplotlib-pyplot) and [backend problems](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4706614/12046409).

Comment: @JohanC excellent, using `mpl.use('agg')` solved the problem and the 12 s are vanished. Now the call is within milliseconds. Thanks.